# Variable in Flask static files routing [url_for('static', filename='')]

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a simple music app.
I want to allow users upload their audio files and I have a page where I'm planning to show all songs.
I've created a template, and the structure looks like:

```
{% for song in songs %}
    <div class="chart-item">
        <div class="chart-position col-md-1">
            <h3>#u</h3>
        </div> <!-- chart-position -->
        <div class="band-logo col-md-2">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/{{ song['artistName'] }}/{{ song['pathToCover'] }}')}}">
        </div> <!-- band-logo -->
        <div class="band-name-and-autio col-md-9">
            <div class="band-name">{{ song['artistName'] }} - {{ song['songName'] }}</div> <!-- band-name -->
            <div class="audio">
                <audio>

                </audio>
            </div> <!-- audio -->
        </div> <!-- band-name-and-autio -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div> <!-- chart-item -->
{% endfor %}
```

Here I want to make a dynamical path to cover image and a record, but I do not know to correctly write the path to the file here:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/{{ song['artistName'] }}/{{ song['pathToCover'] }}')}}">
```

Please, explain how to do it. I've tried to find the solution on flask web page, but for now I have no any result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't believe you can nest template tags like that. But you also shouldn't need to.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/') }}{{ song['artistName'] }}/{{ song['pathToCover'] }}">
```

You can see why this works from the following example:

```
>>> from flask import Flask, url_for
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> with app.test_request_context():
...    print url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/')
/static/uploads/users/
```

So then you just need to add the `artistName`, `/`, `pathToCover`

Comment: I do not think, that I understand your answer, but it gave me an idea. Here is my code : <pre><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/') }}{{ song['artistName']}}/{{ song['pathToCover'] }} "></pre>

Comment: Yup, as I said in my answer, stop nesting template tags. Just run them into each other instead.

Comment: A year has gone, but I've made it. I accept your answer=)

Comment: Thanks Nodarl :) I'm glad you've made it through another year.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/users/'+ song['artistName']+'/'+ song['pathToCover'])}}">
```

It works for me :)

Comment: This works for me :)
`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/app/'+data['image']) }}" alt="{{data.image}}">`

Thanks @Bones and Teeth