# img tag src variable url not working

Tags: html, django, jinja2

So I have my views.py in Django which is rendering a list of objects to my html template. Everything is working fine. Now, the objects have some object ID associated to them. And I have named the images in the 'static/images/' directory the same as the object ID.

So image 1.jpg will correspond to object with object id = 1, 2.jpg for object id = 2 and so on.

Now i want to load image in my img tag in my html, but the src URL of the img tag will depend on the object id.

Following is my html template:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <li class="card" id="card">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="card-image-container" id="card-image-container">
                    <img class="card-image" id="card-image" data-card-id="{{result.id}}" src="{% static 'images/{{ result.id}}.jpg' %}">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="card-info-container" id="card-info-container">
                    <p> {{ result.card_name }} </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The above is not working as the html is not able to parse {{result.id}}.
If i hard code the value of url say like this:

```
src="{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}"
```

then the above successfully loads the 1.jpg for all the li elements, but what i want is the url to be formed according to the {{result.id}} value.

I've tried using the solution given in the following links, but none worked for me.

Links -> [Reference template variable within Jinja expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024551/reference-template-variable-within-jinja-expression)

[Variable within filename in jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400320/variable-within-filename-in-jinja2)

[Variable in Flask static files routing [url_for('static', filename='')]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511175/variable-in-flask-static-files-routing-url-forstatic-filename)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_static_prefix` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix)):

```
{% load static %}
<img class="card-image" id="card-image" data-card-id="{{result.id}}" src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/{{ result.id}}.jpg">
```

Comment: If i'm directly using get_static_prefix in my url as you mentioned in your answer, then do I need to specify its value in settings.py or what? Coz using the above is giving me an TemplateSyntaxError which says Invalid block tag on line 17: 'get_static_prefix', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
So just like i need to load static before using {% static %} in my html, do i also need to load {% get_static_prefix %} or something?

Comment: The documentation I linked states simply using `{% load static %}` should be enough, I've amended my answer.

Comment: Yea, it worked..!! I was not loading static initially as i thought that i'm already loading static from staticfiles. But after loading static also, it worked. Thanks..!!